# xml parsing and spliting in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, xml-parsing, filesplitting

I want to split a **sub xml from mail xml** with the help of the node name. Can some one help?

sample.xml

```
<div>
<a>A
<b>B
<c>C</c>
</b>
<d>D</d>
</a>
</div>
```

I want to split the sub xml that contains B using Scala.

Comment: Scala has a library for xml manipulation https://github.com/scala/scala-xml Also, what have you tried already? Could you provide us some runnable code that we can copy-paste into IDE and tune in from there?

Comment: I have not tried anything still,I am new to scala,can you pls tell me how this library can help me?

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the required xml subtree. Refer [scala xml parsing](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/xml-parsing-xpath-extract-xml-tag-attributes)

```
val x = <div><a>A<b>B<c>C</c></b><d>D</d></a></div>
val b = x \ "a" \ "b"
```

Comment: Thks,I am getting this in my ide after executing b: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(),how to get the value of b?